# DLL References into Application but not Class Library

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I am trying to integrate the `WeifenLuo.WinformsUI.Docking` assembly into my application. To rule out external factors I created a new .Net 4 Winforms app and reference the DLL. Works fine.

I then created a .Net 4 Class Library and referenced the DLL. This this doesn't work and as soon as I try to use anything in that Docking namespace it won't compile.

To recap

`C# Exe ---reference--> WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.dll // OK`

`C# Class library ---reference--> WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.dll // Not OK`

I also have the [WeifenLuo source](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite) and confirmed it's a class library referencing the same version of .Net. I tried adding a class library in their sample solution and referencing the `WinForms` project directly (not the result in assembly) and it still isn't linking properly.

**Updating with Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: You added the DLL reference to your class library, your class library can access dll's classes, but not your WinForm application. If you want to access the dll's classes in WinForm then you will need the reference in your WinForm application as well, Otherwise you can only access it through your Class Library.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I have a third party DLL that when referenced by an application project works fine but not when referenced from a class library. My intention is not to reference anything from the forms application from the class library. I amended my question to hopefully clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Does it give a specific error? Perhaps the DLL has a dependency on another DLL only found in winforms projects (by default). You may have to make your class library make a reference to something like System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: @JasonDown I cranked up the verbosity of Visual Studio and don't see much. The only error is the `Expected class, delegate, ...` where I defined the `DockPanel` object because it can't resolve it. I like your nested dependency theory though, let me try that.

Comment: @JasonDown I matched the references the application had, no change. Darn, I was hoping that would be it.

Comment: Bah I thought that would be it for sure =\

Comment: Looking at your screenshot though, the Test class library doesn't seem to have a reference to the WeifenLuo.WinForms library. I don't see it anywhere on the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare a private variable Inside a namespace.

Try the following code

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel dockPannel;
    }
}
```

And if it still doesn't work, provide the error message.

Comment: Oh my gosh d'oh! Thank you. What an embarrassing mistake.